# How to list all 'files with path' in a windows directory, including all sub-folders in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, flask

I am using Python 3.8.3 64bit with a flask framework.

I am trying to create a list with its path of all files in a directory, including all sub-folders.

My code is

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/slabs'):
    for f in files: 
        print(os.path.join(root, f))
```

However when I print this out, I get all the files with their path and filenames that include the directory in the filename.

For example, I get two entries:

slabs\static\urlimages\1592684282.7557473.png

slabs\static\urlimages1592684282.7557473.png

There is no file called urlimages1592684282.7557473.png, only urlimages\1592684282.7557473.png

How do I only get the files that actually exist or remove the entry that includes the directory and filename together?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

path = os.walk(r'slabs', topdown=True)
for root, dir, files in path:
    for f in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, f))
```

I hope this helps!